# Group by using Linq to get unique records from list

Tags: c#, linq

I have below code for a list, in which I can have duplicate records for list. 
At the final result I need to remove duplicate entries and make them unique. I have written the code as below,

```
public class BusLocation
{
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }

    public string BusNumber { get; set; }
    public Int64 ScheduleId { get; set; }
    public Int64 TripId { get; set; }
}

List<BusLocation> _BusLocation=new List<BusLocation>();
BusLocation loc = new BusLocation();
loc.BusNumber = "123";
loc.Latitude = "12.1234";
loc.Longitude = "44.1234";
loc.ScheduleId = 77;
loc.TripId = 1678;

_BusLocation.Add(loc);

loc.BusNumber = "123";
loc.Latitude = "12.1234";
loc.Longitude = "44.1234";
loc.ScheduleId = 77;
loc.TripId = 1678;

_BusLocation.Add(loc);

loc.BusNumber = "123";
loc.Latitude = "12.1334";
loc.Longitude = "44.1334";
loc.ScheduleId = 78;
loc.TripId = 1679;

_BusLocation.Add(loc);
var result1 = _BusLocation
    .GroupBy(lat => lat.Latitude)
    .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

But its gives me wrong result as the last records are repeated 3 times,
I want the out put  in the list as

```
loc.BusNumber = "123";
loc.Latitude = "12.1234";
loc.Longitude = "44.1234";
loc.ScheduleId = 77;
loc.TripId = 1678;

loc.BusNumber = "123";
loc.Latitude = "12.1334";
loc.Longitude = "44.1334";
loc.ScheduleId = 78;
loc.TripId = 1679;
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: You've only got a single `BusLocation` object. You're adding a reference to that object to the list three times. This has *nothing* to do with LINQ. You need to create separate instances. I suggest you look at object initializers to make all of this cleaner. Additionally, please take the time to format your code more carefully in future - look at the preview before hitting post, and check that it really looks how you'd want it to look if you were trying to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a bug. Instead of adding three distinct `BusLocation` instances to the list you add the same instance three times. You can fix your code and make it more terse by using initializers:

```
List<BusLocation> _BusLocation = new List<BusLocation>() {
  new BusLocation {
    BusNumber = "123",
    Latitude = "12.1234",
    Longitude = "44.1234",
    ScheduleId = 77,
    TripId = 1678
  },
  new BusLocation {
    Latitude = "12.1234",
    Longitude = "44.1234",
    ScheduleId = 77,
    TripId = 1678
  },
  new BusLocation {
    BusNumber = "123",
    Latitude = "12.1334",
    Longitude = "44.1334",
    ScheduleId = 78,
    TripId = 1679
  }
};
```

To remove duplicates you need to define what is a duplicate. You can do that by creating an `IEqualityComparer<BusLocation>` class:

```
class BusLocationEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<BusLocation> {

  public Boolean Equals(BusLocation x, BusLocation y) {
    return x.BusNumber == y.BusNumber
      && x.Latitude == y.Latitude
      && x.Longitude == y.Longitude;
  }

  public Int32 GetHashCode(BusLocation obj) {
    unchecked {
      const Int32 Multiplier = -1521134295;
      var hash = -1901080290;
      hash = hash*Multiplier + obj.Latitude?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
      hash = hash*Multiplier + obj.Longitude?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
      hash = hash*Multiplier + obj.BusNumber?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
      return hash;
    }
  }

}
```

Here equality is defined as having the same bus number, latitude and longitude. However, as you are using strings for latitude and longitude I am not sure that will work but I will leave that to you.

To get the distinct bus locations you can then use LINQ:

```
var distinctBusLocations = _BusLocation.Distinct(new BusLocationEqualityComparer());
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to use Distinct() function. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx

It would look similar like this:

```
var result1 = _BusLocation.GroupBy(lat => lat.Latitude).Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList().Distinct();
```

Comment: Why sooo `ToList()`?

Comment: Yes, are right. I've just copy-pasted Sangeetha's code.

Comment: Bit it will not work because author add the same instance of the object 3 times and `Distinct()` behavior will be differ with expected.